# check button value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a certain text appear when clicking on an element when the button has a certain text. however the same text of the first if statement keeps appearing.

this is the button:

```
<button class="game-button">Start spel</button>
```

These are the table elements:

```
<div id="speelveld">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
$(".game-button").click(function(){
    $(".game-button").html("Reset spel");
});

if ($(".game-button").val() == "Start spel") {
    $("#speelveld tr td").click(function() {
       alert("Je kunt nog niet beginnen");
    });
} else {
    $("#speelveld tr td").click(function() {
       alert("hoi");
    });
}
```

my question is: how can I make a certain alert appear when the button has a certain text

Comment: You are binding event inside the `if`. So only the event inside `if` gets registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the handler on the `td` based on a condition which is never met.

Modify your handler to check for the value of the button every time one cell of the table is clicked.

```
$(".game-button").click(function(){
    $(".game-button").text("Reset spel");
});

$("#speelveld tr td").click(function() {
    if ($(".game-button").text() === "Start spel") {    
       alert("Je kunt nog niet beginnen");
    }
    else {
        alert("hoi");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event inside the `if`. So only the event inside `if` gets registered

This is what you need to do:

```
    $("#speelveld tr td").click(function() {
       if ($(".game-button").html() == "Start spel") {
         alert("Je kunt nog niet beginnen");
       } else {            
         alert("hoi");            
       }

    });
```